# Windows 10 installation on Dell T7600 with PERC H310 Raid Controller

Tags: hardware-raid, windows-10, drivers, disk-image, clonezilla

We work in an environment with machines running mostly CentOS 7.3 but from times to times we need to switch to Windows 10.

To manage those changes, we have a PXE boot solution with tree options:

1. boot currently locally installed OS
2. reinstall CentOS (minimal OS with SaltStack recipe)
3. reinstall Windows 10 (restore a clone of a Windows 10 disk image with clonezilla)

The issue we're facing is that **Windows 10 doesn't support the Raid Controller PERC H310**. So basically, when restoring the Windows image, we can't boot on it because Windows doesn't find the drives. 
Same issue when trying a clean install, Windows doesn't find any local disk.

I've tested every solution I've found like testing with previous version driver during Windows install... doesn't help so far.

Also, I'm sure of the issue since when attaching the drive directly to the motherboard (so skipping the raid controller) it works.

Any suggested solutions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a situation that would be better resolved with virtualization.

Comment: What do you suggest exactly? Why virtualisation?

Comment: By using a virtual machine with Windows 10 on it, you can avoid having to reimage your machine each time you need Windows 10, you can simply start it up and use it whenever you need it. There are many options out there, it's simply a matter of choosing what works for your organization and use case.

Comment: Those workstations are for graphic usage so from my experience, virtualisation is not the good option. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: a new version of Windows 10 Pro for Workstations could maybe help you out this fall too if you can wait.**

> [Windows 10 Pro for Workstations](https://blogs.windows.com/business/2017/08/10/microsoft-announces-windows-10-pro-workstations/#Rcpkqr7jUg6450RO.97) is a high-end edition of Windows 10
>   Pro, comes with unique support for server grade PC hardware and is
>   designed to meet demanding needs of mission critical and compute
>   intensive workloads.
>
> - Expanded hardware support

---

You will need to preinstall the driver to make it work (slipstream) or to give the setup the driver.

The easiest way, in the setup, some other forum give that file to get to give the setup the driver

http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER04120408M/1/WINPE10.0-DRIVERS-A04-942XJ.CAB

and copy those folder to an USB stick and you will be ready to install

T7600-win10-A01-0P54F\T7600\win10\x64\storage\6DD29_A00-00\x64\iaStorS

T7600-win10-A01-0P54F\T7600\win10\x86\storage\6DD29_A00-00\x86\iaStorS

Comment: That's indeed the solution I've finally found out also. The link I used is different so I'll add this second source: 
https://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER03538550M/1/T7600-win10-A01-0P54F.CAB
http://www.dell.com/support/home/be/fr/bebsdt1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=0P54F

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the dreaded H310 vs Win10 issue during an upgrade from win7.
I know this post is old, but this may save some one a lot of time!!!

THERE IS NO DRIVER!

... a day of my life looking and trying every driver out there...

disable the onboard RAID controller from system bios.
Installed LSI 9211-8i card(about $100) and reroute the HDD cage's cable to the new card.
move the boot drive to one of the sata ports (was being used by DVD drive)
Boot to win7 and allowed it to install the driver for the new card.
Moved boot drive back to HDD cage and ran the windows 10 upgrade successfully!

Notes: system bios to A16, LSI card flash was 20.x.x.xIR. the 9211 has the correct SFF-8087 mini-SAS connector that matches up with Dell's hot swap cage. There is an IT flash for the 9211 if you wanna skip the boot delay and have no need for RAID.

Hope this helps

Comment: The accepted answer mentions that there is a driver.